# wordpress programmatically add post tags

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to programmatically add post tags to a new post using PHP and JS.
I have the code that sends using ajax the id's I want to add, PHP check them if exists, if not create them. Then it searches by name, and send back to Ajax the ID's.

My problem resides in adding all post tags to post, since only the last one adds itselfs to post.

```
success: function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        console.log(obj.term_id);
        wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({tags: [obj.term_id]})
    }
},
```

Console.log writes all post tags ID's that should be added. When using `wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({tags: [obj.term_id]})` inside the for loop, it only adds the last ID to the post. In my specific case I have two ID's, one for each post tag (id 51 and 110) but it only adds the ID 110 to the post.

Isn't supposed to add both since it's inside a for loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guess without knowing anything about the  `wp.data` api is you want to create the full array of values and only call `editPost()` once ... passing in the whole array.

You can use `Array#map()` to create the full array of terms from `data`.

Something like:

```
success: function(data) {

    var termsArray = data.map(function(el){ 
        return el.term_id; 
    });

    wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').editPost({tags: termsArray})

},
```